# Groupwise maximum works on table but not on view

Tags: mysql, view

I have a query that produces the rows of the maximum of a group. It works on a table but fails to work on a view. The Group By does not work. The code is below;

```
SELECT View1.timestamp, View1.person_name
  FROM View1
 WHERE View1.timestamp IN
 (
    SELECT MAX(View1.timestamp)
    FROM View1
    GROUP BY View1.person_name
 )
```

What did I do wrong? Can Group By work properly on Views? I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` works in an inline view, and it works in a stored view.

It's not clear what you mean by "fails to work". Is the query producing wrong or unexpected results? Is it throwing an error message? Or, is performance G_L_A_C_I_A_L?

That NOT IN (subquery) predicate is a real dog. For every row returned from the outer query, MySQL is going to run that subquery. And if that is a query on a view, then MySQL is going to run the view query first, materialize the result as a temporary MyISAM table, and then run the query against that.

Here's a picture of what's happening when you run that query...

```
execute View1 query from outermost query
  populate temporary MyISAM table with the results
  fetch first row
    evaluate IN predicate
      execute subquery to get the list to compare to
        execute view1 query
          populate temporary MyISAM table with results
          find MAX value from MyISAM table  
        populate another temporary MyISAM table with found MAX values
        search the MyISAM table to see if the value from the row matches or not
  fetch next row
    evaluate IN predicate
      execute subquery to get the list to compare to
        execute view1 query
          populate temporary MyISAM table with results
          find MAX value from MyISAM table  
        populate another temporary MyISAM table with found MAX values
        search the MyISAM table to see if the value from the row matches or not
  fetch next row
    evaluate IN predicate
       ...
```

And that's a whole lot of overhead being done, for each row. All that overhead adds up with large sets.

A much more efficient approach to return an equivalent resultset) is to use a join operation, e.g.

```
SELECT v.*
  FROM View1 v
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(m.timestamp)
           FROM View1 m
          GROUP BY m.person_name
       ) p
    ON p.timestamp = v.timestamp
```

With this approach, the execution plan looks more like this:

```
execute View1 query and materialize results as temporary MyISAM table m 
execute MAX query against m and populate temporary MyISAM table p
execute View1 query and materialize results as temporary MyISAM table v
execute outermost query to find matching rows from temporary tables p and v
```

That View1 query gets executed two times, but at least it's only two times. There's still overhead, but it's a lot better than executing the View1 query for every single row returned from View1.

Again, it's not clear what you mean when you say "fails to work".

It's a bit odd that your query does a GROUP BY on person_name, but there is no reference to person_name in the outer query.

If the intent is to find the "latest" row for each person, then we'd include a predicate to match on person_name as well as timestamp, like this:

```
SELECT v.*
  FROM ( SELECT m.person_name
              , MAX(m.timestamp) AS latest_timestamp
           FROM View1 m
          GROUP BY m.person_name
       ) p
  JOIN View1 v
   AND v.person_name = p.person_name
   AND v.timestamp = p.latest_timestamp
```

---

But I'm not sure any of that helps answer what you are asking.

---

**UPDATE***

To get the same kind of `person_name` match as shown in the previous query, but using an `IN (subquery)` predicate, you could use a correlated subquery, and a GROUP BY is not required.

**NOTE:** with large sets, this approach is usually a lot less efficient than a join operation. It suffers the same kind of performance overhead "for each row" problem as the original query; the correlated subquery gets re-executed for every row from `v`.

```
SELECT v.timestamp
     , v.person_name
  FROM View1 v
 WHERE v.timestamp IN
       ( SELECT MAX(m.timestamp)
           FROM View1 m
          WHERE m.person_name = v.person_name
       )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have been a great help. The last code segment works but some minor changes are required. I have made the editing. What puzzles me is why my query which uses GROUP BY does not work. There were two rows with the same person_name being returned. If the GROUP BY works, that should not happen

Comment: @user3293156: Likely, there are two rows with the same timestamp but different person_name. Your query finds the latest timestamp for each person_name just fine; but your query matches that found latest timestamp to _all_ rows that have the same timestamp. Your query doesn't have a restriction that the person_name also needs to match. The second query in my answer demonstrates how to include the match on person_name.